# T-SQL's equivalent of Oracle's %TYPE operator?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, plsql, param

When writing a procedure in PL/SQL, I can declare a parameter's type as myTable.myColumn%TYPE so that when I alter myColumn's type from say varchar2(20) to varchar2(50) I don't have to change the procedure's parameter type. Is there something similar in T-SQL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no equivalent in T-SQL.

Comment: It's 2015 and there's still no equivalent. Disappointing SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

The best that you could do would be to create a user-defined data type, then you could change the underlying UDT and it would take effect in both places.

This would affect it everywhere that you use it, so if you used the type in multiple tables it would affect them all if you changed it.