# Data-Type mapping in SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, oracle10g, mapping, sqldatatypes, data-mapping

Is there a way to declare mapped data-types in SQL Server 2005, something like Oracle's `%Type`:

`Declare a  emp.sal%type` 
where data-type of `a` will be same as `sal` field of `emp` table

or `Declare a emp%rowtype`
where data-types of `a` will be same as each row of `emp` table.

I have googled it,but couldn't find it.

Comment: Are you talking about something like this http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+CLR/userdefineddatatypesinsqlserver2005/1979/

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL's equivalent of Oracle's %TYPE operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849396/t-sqls-equivalent-of-oracles-type-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle %TYPE attribute adapts code as table definitions change. If the column's type changes, the variable adapts to use the correct type during run time. This enables data independence without requiring to know the exact data types to be assigned for a variable or database column.

Microsoft SQL Server does **NOT** support and has no equivalent of Oracle %TYPE.

Comment: Bolstering this answer with references: "This can't be done in SQL Server in a straight forward manner." - [Does SQL Server have functionality like Oracle's %Type Attribute](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/does-sql-server-have-functionallity-like-oracles-type-attribute) and 
"Microsoft SQL Server does not support and has no equivalent of Oracle %TYPE." -- [Ispirer SQLWays Database Migration Software](https://doc.ispirer.com/sqlways/Output/SQLWays-1-041.html#:~:text=The%20Oracle%20%25TYPE%20attribute%20adapts,independence%20and%20reduces%20maintenance%20costs.)