# Procedure - create table referencing other table column type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hi I know that is possible in PL/SQL to use reference a column type with %TYPE, but I'm wondering if the same thing is available in T-SQL.

```
PROCEDURE ....

CREATE TABLE TABLE_B
(
   ID    NUMBER NOT NULL,
   NAME  TABLE_A.NAME%TYPE
);

... END PROCEDURE
```

Is this possible?

Comment: No: http://doc.ispirer.com/sqlways/Output/SQLWays-1-041.html. It states, "Microsoft SQL Server does not support and has no an equivalent of Oracle %TYPE."  or MSFT Forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c1a3e39e-ba83-4573-82b6-4ddedb626d21/sql-server-equivalent-of-oracles-tablecolumnnametype?forum=transactsql  If your table's data type is likely to change, you can use a user-defined-type in both the table and the proc.  This will mean that any changes you make to the UDT are made to both the table and the proc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849396/t-sqls-equivalent-of-oracles-type-operator Asked and answered previously as well.  This just shows that since 2009 it's not been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer No:

I'm a big fan of validation so here's 3 sources that all say basically the same thing: No but it can be simulated (albeit painfully) and it adds a layer of complexity to design and maintenance.

References:

1. [Microsoft SQL Server does not support and has no an equivalent of Oracle %TYPE.](http://doc.ispirer.com/sqlways/Output/SQLWays-1-041.html.)
2. [If your table's data type is likely to change, you can use a user-defined-type in both the table and the proc. This will mean that any changes you make to the UDT are made to both the table and the proc](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/)
3. [Migrating to SQL server from Oracle](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/oracle_sql_server_differences_equivalents.htm)

Example of User defined Type:

The %TYPE data type of Oracle, lets you create a variable and have that variable's data type be defined by a table or view column or a PL/SQL package variable.

There is no equivalent for Oracle's %TYPE datatype in T-SQL, but it can be simulated (not very conveniently though) using User Defined Data types (UDT). Here is an example:

```
EXEC sp_addtype 'MyType', 'smallint', NULL

CREATE TABLE MyTable (i MyType)

CREATE PROC MyProc
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @i MyType
END
```